# IndentationError: expected an indented block. 38 строка

Tags: python

Ошибка IndentationError: expected an indented block на 38 строке.
Весь код:

```
# импорт модулей
import random
import time

# создание переменных
money = 0
health = 100

# приветствие
print("Добро пожаловать в 'Бесконечную Россию'")
print("Выберите действие:")
print("1) Пойти работать (+ 20 руб.)")
print("2) По спать (+10 здоровья)")
print("3) Купить лотерейный билет (- 25 руб.)")
print("4) Пойти погулять (+10 здоровья. Возможно случиться какая-то неприятность, и будет минус к здоровью)")
print("5) Стата")
answer = input("")

# выбор и что за ним последует
if answer == "1":
    print("Подождите 40 секунд")
    time.sleep(40)
    money += 20
    print("Вы заработали 20 рублей!")
    print("Теперь ваш баланс", money, "руб.")
    # перейти к "Выберите действие"
if answer == "2":
    if health == 100:
        print("Ваш запас здоровья на максимуме, если вы поспите то вам не прибавиться здоровье. ")
        print("Если вы хотите продолжить нажмите 'y', потом [ENTER]. Если хотите вернуться к началу нажмите 'n', а потом [ENTER]")
        answer_sleep = input("")
        if answer_sleep == "y":
            print("Подождите 30 секунд.")
            time.sleep(30)
            # перейти к "Выберите действие"
        if answer_sleep == "n":
            # перейти к "Выберите действие"
    elif health < 80:
        print("Подождите 30 секунд")
        time.sleep(30)
        health += 20
        print("Вам добавлено 20 жизней. Теперь у вас", health, "жизней")
    else:
        print("Подождите 30 секунд")
        time.sleep(30)
        print("Ваш запас здоровья полностью востановлено")
if answer == "3":
    if money > 25:
        money -= 25
        number = random.randint(100, 999)
        print("Ваш номер билета", number)
        print("Подождите 10 секунд, мы проверяем какой билет выиграл")
        chance_to_win = random.randint(1, 100)
        timw.sleep(10)
        if chance_to_win == 100:
            money += 20000
            print("Поздравляем! Вы выиграли 20 000 рублей! Теперь на вашем балансе", money, "руб.")
        else:
            print("Сожалеем, но ваш номер билета не выиграл.")
    else:
        print("Вам не хватает денег для покупки лотерейного билета")
if answer == "4":
    chance_to_trouble = random.randint(1,50)
    if chance_to_trouble == 2:
        print("Вы решили пойти погулять.")
        print("Подождите 15 секунд.")
        time.sleep(15)
        health -= 5
        print("Вы споткнулись. Ваше здоровье уменьшилось на 5. Теперь у вас", health, "здоровья")
    elif chance_to_trouble == 4:
        print("Вы решили пойти погулять.")
        print("Подождите 15 секунд.")
        time.sleep(15)
        health -= 15
        print("Вы решили проехаться на самокате, и упали с него. Ваше здоровье уменьшено на 15. Теперьу вас", health, "здоровья")
    elif chance_to_trouble == 10:
        print("Вы решили пойти погулять.")
        print("Подождите 15 секунд.")
        time.sleep(15)
        health -= 30
        print("Вы решили покататься на велосипеде, ив врезались в стену. Ваше здоровье уменьшено на 30. Теперь у вас", health, "здоровья")
    else:
        if health < 90:
            print("Вы погуляля, без проишествий. Вам добавлено 10 жизней. Теперь у вас", health, "здоровья")
        else:
            print("Вы погуляли без проишествий. Вас запас здоровья полностью восстановлен")
if answer == "5":
    print("У вас", health, "здоровья")
    print("У вас", money, "рублей")
```

Содержание строки:
`elif health < 80:`
Сразу говорю, код ещё далеко не дописан, поэтому советов по остальной части кода не надо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает, потому что вы после `if answer_sleep == "n":` не написали никакого действия, а по правилам так не положено.
Если вы хотите пока что оставить там "пустоту", то напишите в теле `if` строку `pass` так:

```
# импорт модулей
import random
import time

# создание переменных
money = 0
health = 100

# приветствие
print("Добро пожаловать в 'Бесконечную Россию'")
print("Выберите действие:")
print("1) Пойти работать (+ 20 руб.)")
print("2) По спать (+10 здоровья)")
print("3) Купить лотерейный билет (- 25 руб.)")
print("4) Пойти погулять (+10 здоровья. Возможно случиться какая-то неприятность, и будет минус к здоровью)")
print("5) Стата")
answer = input("")

# выбор и что за ним последует
if answer == "1":
    print("Подождите 40 секунд")
    time.sleep(40)
    money += 20
    print("Вы заработали 20 рублей!")
    print("Теперь ваш баланс", money, "руб.")
    # перейти к "Выберите действие"
if answer == "2":
    if health == 100:
        print("Ваш запас здоровья на максимуме, если вы поспите то вам не прибавиться здоровье. ")
        print("Если вы хотите продолжить нажмите 'y', потом [ENTER]. Если хотите вернуться к началу нажмите 'n', а потом [ENTER]")
        answer_sleep = input("")
        if answer_sleep == "y":
            print("Подождите 30 секунд.")
            time.sleep(30)
            # перейти к "Выберите действие"
        if answer_sleep == "n":
            # перейти к "Выберите действие"
            pass                        # <-----
    elif health < 80:
        print("Подождите 30 секунд")
        time.sleep(30)
        health += 20
        print("Вам добавлено 20 жизней. Теперь у вас", health, "жизней")
    else:
        print("Подождите 30 секунд")
        time.sleep(30)
        print("Ваш запас здоровья полностью востановлено")
if answer == "3":
    if money > 25:
        money -= 25
        number = random.randint(100, 999)
        print("Ваш номер билета", number)
        print("Подождите 10 секунд, мы проверяем какой билет выиграл")
        chance_to_win = random.randint(1, 100)
        timw.sleep(10)
        if chance_to_win == 100:
            money += 20000
            print("Поздравляем! Вы выиграли 20 000 рублей! Теперь на вашем балансе", money, "руб.")
        else:
            print("Сожалеем, но ваш номер билета не выиграл.")
    else:
        print("Вам не хватает денег для покупки лотерейного билета")
if answer == "4":
    chance_to_trouble = random.randint(1,50)
    if chance_to_trouble == 2:
        print("Вы решили пойти погулять.")
        print("Подождите 15 секунд.")
        time.sleep(15)
        health -= 5
        print("Вы споткнулись. Ваше здоровье уменьшилось на 5. Теперь у вас", health, "здоровья")
    elif chance_to_trouble == 4:
        print("Вы решили пойти погулять.")
        print("Подождите 15 секунд.")
        time.sleep(15)
        health -= 15
        print("Вы решили проехаться на самокате, и упали с него. Ваше здоровье уменьшено на 15. Теперьу вас", health, "здоровья")
    elif chance_to_trouble == 10:
        print("Вы решили пойти погулять.")
        print("Подождите 15 секунд.")
        time.sleep(15)
        health -= 30
        print("Вы решили покататься на велосипеде, ив врезались в стену. Ваше здоровье уменьшено на 30. Теперь у вас", health, "здоровья")
    else:
        if health < 90:
            print("Вы погуляля, без проишествий. Вам добавлено 10 жизней. Теперь у вас", health, "здоровья")
        else:
            print("Вы погуляли без проишествий. Вас запас здоровья полностью восстановлен")
if answer == "5":
    print("У вас", health, "здоровья")
    print("У вас", money, "рублей")
```